# Getting problem in setting mindate in datetimepicker bootstrap for the second time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to set mindate on basis of first datetimepicker, its working fine first time but when I setting for second time , its not working properly. What I missing, any suggestion. 
Thanks in advance.

```
$('#start_dateTime').datetimepicker({
minDate: moment()
}).on('dp.change', function (event) {
var start_dateTime = this.value;
$('#end_dateTime').attr('readonly', false);
$('#end_dateTime').datetimepicker({
minDate: moment(start_dateTime)
})
});
```

Comment: share your full code

Comment: @RohitVerma this is full js code

Comment: in variable start_dateTime storing value , but not setting mindate for second time

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for jQuery without using Moment This is for DatePicker Same is applicable for Datetimepicker too.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {        
    $('#startdate_0').datepicker({
        //changeMonth: true, changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        minDate: new Date(),
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#enddate_0").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

    $('#enddate_0').datepicker({
      //  changeMonth: true, changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#startdate_0").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });        
});
```